# Double pointer when in linked list structure

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am new in c++ and I am learning linked list. However, I encountered some trouble.

For the normal case, when we define a linked list, here is the Node structure:

```
struct Node{

   int data;

   Node* next;

};
```

However, how can we define a linked list when the structure become like this:

```
struct Node{

   int data;

   Node** next; // Double pointer instead

};
```

I am quite confused with the double pointer, what should we assign to "next"?
For example, when we are inserting node at the beginning, when we assign the value of head into `newPtr->next`:

`newPtr->next = &head`? Is that right?

Thanks all of you.

Comment: Why don't you try it? There are myriads of samples and tutorials available how to do linked lists.

Comment: Double pointers mean : next is pointing at an array that contains pointers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with this but I just want to share my thoughts since I'm also beginning to learn about pointers. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```js
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 int **p = new int*; // Pointer to a pointer.
 int *q = new int; // Pointer.
 
 // Assigning the value of 5 to where q points to. 
 // The "*" is used as a dereference operator
 // meaning that it assigns 5 to where q is pointing to.
 *q=5;
 
 // Here you are pointing p to point to q.
 // That is why it is called a pointer to a pointer.
 // The "*" here is used as pointer to point to another pointer.
 *p=q;

 // Then here you can access the value of the p by dereferencing 
 // it twice.
 
 std::cout << **p << std::endl;
 
 // Outputs 5.
 
 return 0;
}
```

As what the others said in the comments you are creating a pointer to a pointer. int *p means it can point to a data directly while int **q means it can point to another pointer, in this case *p. The number of * tells how deep you are going. Assuming that you want your Node to have a two pointers, then you have to do something like this:

```js
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *next, *prev;
}
```

It is also called Doubly Linked List. Where you can traverse forward and backward.